# C# EF Core converting object to string / get; set

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I do get a stack overflow when trying to convert an object to a string in C#. I'm making an API Call to an endpoint and pass the response to this class. As the ef core does not support the datatype “object” I'm trying to convert this datatype to string to store it in the database as a column.

I have a class with various attributes like

```cs
public DateTime? start_date_local { get; set; }
public string? timezone { get; set; }
public double? utc_offset { get; set; }
```

some of them are from type object:

```cs
[NotMapped]
public object? start_latlng { get; set; }
```

As this datatype is not supported, I'm not mapping this to the DB, but I'm trying to convert this into a string and store it within a second datatype which can be inserted into the DB.

```cs
public string start_latlng2
{
    get { return start_latlng2; }
    set { start_latlng2 = Convert.ToString(start_latlng); }
}
```

This does not seem to work as I always get an error like:

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 19126 times:
--------------------------------
   at SportAnalytics.DataModel.Activity.get_start_latlng2()
--------------------------------
   at DynamicClass.lambda_method171(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.EnsureOriginalValues()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntrySubscriber.SnapshotAndSubscribe(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: why you want to use object type? You can try like this

`public class Test{
     public Test1 start_latlng {get;set;}

}

public class Test1{
      public string Attr1 {get;set}
      public string Attr2 {get;set}
}`

Comment: In your property setter you call your property setter again, leading to an endless loop, resulting in the stack overflow exception. Change your setter code to set your backing field and not the property again.

Comment: @Oliver how do I do this, sorry, haven´t really worked with the setter stuff yet. is it than value = Convert.ToString(start_latlng); or how should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The StackoverflowException comes from the wrong definition of your property. You should write it with an explicit back field.

```
private string _start_latlng2;
public string start_latlng2
{
    get { return _start_latlng2; }
    set { _start_latlng2 = value; }
}
```

In your case you should use an explicit read-only property, that will be called when  needed:

```
public string start_latlng2
{
    get { return start_latlng == null ? null : Convert.ToString(start_latlng); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
public class Test{      
   public Test1 start_latlng {get;set;}  
}

public class Test1{       
   public string Attr1 {get;set}
   public string Attr2 {get;set}
}
```

Comment: not sure how this should actually help

Answer (score 0):

@Oliver

sorry for asking once again a silly questions, but I just got started with C# a few weeks back.

I have now set something like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public object? start_latlng { get; set; } // was object

private string? _start_latlng2;
public string? start_latlng2
{
    get { return start_latlng == null ? null : Convert.ToString(start_latlng); }
    set { _start_latlng2 = value; }
}
```

If I run the debugger once again, I can see that the original object is an array like ["49,11", "49,12"], the start_latlng2 is also set like a string "["49,11", "49,12"]" which is fine and ok for me to be added to the database like this, but the column in sql keeps empty and I don´t know why because the property in the debugger is set correctly.

Can you once again maybe quickly explain how your suggestion

```
private string _start_latlng2;
public string start_latlng2
{
    get { return _start_latlng2; }
    set { _start_latlng2 = value; }
}
```

corresponds to transforming an object to an string? Your suggestion here just covers how you can access private fields with those getters and setters or? I really would like to understand how I can convert an object to string working with getters and setters. Maybe you can explain that once more, thank you very miuch Oliver!

Comment: It would be better to edit your question or post a comment under Oliver's response.   The answer section is not for questions :)

Comment: It´s better to comment on a question when you have a follow-up question or to post a new question if that is appropriate.